# Force Long URL's to break with responsive div width 100% for html emails

Tags: css, html-email, line-breaks, word-wrap, word-break

I am trying to create html e-mails that are responsive, I have the following row with two table datas, one of which contains a very long URL the other an image. I have tried everything, to make the URL break responsively, but it doesn't work in outlook.com, outlook 2011, iphone 4s and iphone5. what is the problem?

```
    <td style="padding:0px 30px 0px 10px;max-Width: 500px; height:auto;display: inline-block; word-break: break-all;">
            <div style="padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;width:100%;height:auto;font-size:12px;color:#999999; text-align:left; border: solid #999999 1px; line-height: 1.1em;word-wrap: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;word-break:break-all; word-break:break-word;-webkit-hyphens: auto; -moz-hyphens: auto;-ms-hyphens:auto; hyphens: auto;">
                    <pre><code><p style=" word-wrap: break-word;">
&lt;a href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.hi.com?utm_source%3Dexpert%2520sium%3Dexpert%2520badCNQcMIQSH8F4dPpFoA" rel="nofollow"&gt;&lt;img src="h1.png" alt="Expert"width="125px" height="125px"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
                     </p></code></pre>
            </div>

      </td>
     <td><img></td>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to just make a link of it? <a href="the long link">Link</a>. This way, in the mail it only says "Link" and not the long url.

Comment: How about `word-wrap: break-word;`

Comment: Because I want the user to be able to copy paste the link and use it in their websites. I need the user to see the link

Comment: word-wrap:break word is not working in chrome and outlook.com

Comment: CSS support in email clients is extremely spotty: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/. Are you able to shorten the URL at all?

Comment: no I don't think I can shorten the Url, unless i push it through and create a tinyURL, but how will this help ? it still wont respond?

Comment: I changed the table to have a fixed layout, and it is half working now, however the image is td is too big. its half the screen size (thats what a fixed table does) but I would like it to be maybe 1/4 of the screen size.

Comment: @ElinaLulle http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-break

Answer (score 6):

```
style="word-break: break-all"
```

If you wrap your overtly long URL in a div with that styling, that should be a satisfactory quick win.